# I want code to remove option from dropdown after its selection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want code to remove option from dropdown after its selection in JavaScript. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
selectBox = document.getElementById("mySelectBoxId");
toRemove = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
selectBox.removeChild(toRemove);
```

anyway I recommend that you use jQuery or MooTools (or any JavaScript framework) instead of using brute JavaScript.

Comment: $("#mySelectBoxId").remove("#mySelectBoxId option:selected")); this should work (I do not have time to test it right now), when do you want it triggered onchange?I'd recommend ondblclick. tell me if it works as it is